# RDLC Report Viewer expression returning #ERROR with IIF expression

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, rdlc, reportviewer

Can somebody tell me what is wrong? This is my RDLC expression:

```
=IIF(Last(Fields!totalHour.Value) <> "" OR "--:--" , "Total Hours  " & Last(Fields!totalHour.Value), " ")
```

And it is returning **#ERROR**

I don't know if it is happening because it returns a null value, but if it is what should i do?

And if i set to always show the value it works:

```
=Last(Fields!totalHour.Value)
```

I also tried this and it keeps sending the same error:

```
=IIF(Last(Fields!totalHour.Value) <> "" OR "--:--" OR "00:00" , "Total Hours  " & Last(Fields!totalHour.Value), " ")
```

This is the information that is passing to my dataset : `"00:00"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix the issue you are comparing string, not int. Your expression will work if it is an int but fail if the value is a string so you need to write it separately like below.

```
=IIF(Last(Fields!totalHour.Value) <> "" OR Last(Fields!totalHour.Value) <> "--:--" , "Total Hours  " & Last(Fields!totalHour.Value), " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it will not work for everybody, but for the solution i just made one camparision and it worked!

```
=IIF(Last(Fields!totalHour.Value) = "00:00" , "Total Hours  " & Last(Fields!totalHour.Value), " ")
```